# CSS forced top z-index with parent overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position, z-index

I can't sort out how to move the element, which is placed under `.content-wrapper{ overflow:hidden; .content{position:absolute;} }`, to the very top.

Consider a screenshot below:
[image]

An image element with man photo is placed under the `.content` element. But the part of his head on photo, which is highlighted with yellow (pointed with red arrow) is hidden due to the parent `.content-wrapper` has an `overflow:hidden` property. The main problem is that I **can't** change the hidden overflow to whatever else.

Is that actually real to solve such a problem without using a JavaScript?

## ==== Supplement 1 ====

To clarify the problem, I've made up a code snippet below:

```css
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:initial;
  padding:0 10px;
  background-color:#EEEEEE;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.content-wrapper{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
  margin:10px 0;
  min-height:350px;
}

.content{
  background-color:white;
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  bottom:10px;
}

.content.grayed{
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

.content.positioned{
  top:50px;
  left:180px;
  bottom:-50px; //negative positioned parts supposed to be hidden
  right:-50px;  //as .content-wrapper has overflow:hidden;
}

.content.positioned img{
  width:40%;
  height:auto;
  margin-top:-40vh; //but that is not supposed to be hidden out of .content-wrapper
  margin-left:10vw;
  min-width:250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
.wrapper
<div class="content-wrapper">
.content-wrapper
<div class="content grayed" style="transform: rotate(-35deg); padding:20px;">
<strong>.content</strong> with cut off edges - that is supposed behaviour
</div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
.content-wrapper
<div class="content positioned">
<strong>.content</strong>
<img src="//i.imgur.com/DsOdy1V.png">
<br>
...and a man above is with sliced head - that is UNsupposed behaviour
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Is there really no any solution?

Comment: As long as you use overflow hidden, no script will overcome that, if the photo stays as a child of course, so if you post a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue, we most likely can help you get rid of the `overflow: hidden`

Comment: @LGSon , I have added a code snippet with small example. Could you, please, review it?

Comment: @impulsgraw did you ever get this sorted? It is breaking my heart  been stuck on it for three days, maybe it is impossible

Comment: @peterflanagan Oh I only noticed now that the question is too old :) probably the OP will no more need this ...

Answer (score 5):

I would consider adding the image outside and adjust the position to obtain this. Change the translation to adjust the position:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative; /*change this*/
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  margin: 10px 0;
  min-height: 350px;
}

.content {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.content.grayed {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.content.positioned {
  top: 50px;
  left: 180px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px calc(40% - 0.4*148px) 0 20px; /* the space of the image*/
}

.content.positioned img {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0; /*Hide this one*/
}

.hack {
  /*Don't use any top/bottom here !!*/
  left: 190px;
  right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hack img {
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(70%);
  max-width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  .wrapper
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    .content-wrapper
    <div class="content grayed" style="transform: rotate(-35deg); padding:20px;">
      <strong>.content</strong> with cut off edges - that is supposed behaviour
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hack">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/DsOdy1V.png">
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    .content-wrapper
    <div class="content positioned">
      <strong>.content</strong>
      <img src="//i.imgur.com/DsOdy1V.png">
      <br> ...and a man above is with sliced head - that is UNsupposed behaviour
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<div>` like content-wrapper-inner and move the height, position from content-wrapper into it.

```css
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:initial;
  padding:0 10px;
  background-color:#EEEEEE;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.content-wrapper{
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
  margin:10px 0;
}

.content{
  background-color:white;
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  bottom:10px;
}
.content-wrapper-inner {
  min-height:350px;
  position:relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.content.grayed{
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

.content.positioned{
  top:50px;
  left:180px;
  bottom:-50px; //negative positioned parts supposed to be hidden
  right:-50px;  //as .content-wrapper has overflow:hidden;
}

.content.positioned img{
  width:40%;
  height:auto;
  margin-top:-40vh; //but that is not supposed to be hidden out of .content-wrapper
  margin-left:10vw;
  min-width:250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
.wrapper
<div class="content-wrapper">
.content-wrapper
<div class="content grayed" style="transform: rotate(-35deg); padding:20px;">
<strong>.content</strong> with cut off edges - that is supposed behaviour
</div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
.content-wrapper

<div class="content-wrapper-inner">
<div class="content positioned">
<strong>.content</strong>
<img src="//i.imgur.com/DsOdy1V.png">
<br>
...and a man above is with sliced head - that is UNsupposed behaviour
</div>
</div>
<div class="content positioned">
<strong>.content</strong>
<img src="//i.imgur.com/DsOdy1V.png">
<br>
...and a man above is with sliced head - that is UNsupposed behaviour
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: it seems there is a major issue in your code .. did you forget something? It's scrambled when I run it

Answer (score -1):

Try to make `overflow:visible`of the outer div of the content.

Comment: Did you miss _The main problem is that I can't change the hidden overflow to whatever else_?

Answer (score -1):

You can't have content reach out of a parent with overflow: hidden and still find a way to show the head. The question is why you need overflow hidden on the parent.

Perhaps you could use a sibling element for the image container and limit overflow on the content container.

Something like:

HTML

```
 <div class="parent">
   <div class="child-content-wrapper">
     Content goes here
   </div>
   <div class="child-image">
     Image goes here
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .parent {
    position: relative;
 }

 .child-content-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
 }

 .child-image {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
 }
```

That should work and you'll be able to get the cut off effect on the rotated content box and the whole head.